# Access violation using hog.compute(...) in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I've tried to use the HOG feature extractor of OpenCV (3.2) but it always causes a access violation (sorry about the german text):

```
Ausnahme ausgelöst bei 0x000007FEC6AB12F5 (opencv_world320d.dll) in roi_detect.exe: 0xC0000005: Zugriffsverletzung beim Schreiben an Position 0x0000000000000000.
```

I've already tried to use multiple parameters and images of different sizes, but this exception is caused any time.

Please take a look at following code-snipped:

```
cv::Mat mat = cv::imread(input, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);    
cv::Mat res;
cv::Size size(128, 128);
cv::resize(mat, res,size);
cv::HOGDescriptor hog(cv::Size(128,128), cv::Size(8, 8), cv::Size(4,4), cv::Size(4, 4), 9);
std::cout << "Computing HOGs..." << std::endl;
hog.compute(res, descriptor);
std::cout << "Computed HOGs" << std::endl;
```

I've actually resized the image to the size of the "WinSize" parameter, even if some sources say that it's actually not the cause to this issue.

Comment: Which compiler? Debug or release build? And please, make a full [mcve] that reproduces the problem (something we can just compile without having to add any more code)

Comment: I'll provide the full code soon. MSVC14 and in both, debug and release. The dlls are also VC14 builds.

Comment: I've updated the question accordingly. You actually just have to read the image as grayscale.

Comment: "Access violation at write to position 0x00000000000000" means that the code is trying to write to a pointer which address is 0: In other words, you have an invalid pointer. Find it using a debugger.

Comment: Well, but that's actually a problem of the implementation or can you tell from the simple code snipped up there why I've an invalid pointer? The HOG extractor has several assertions and my parameters are valid but it still seems almost impossible to get it running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to the problem in case that other people run into the same problem.

Make sure that the release versions of the OpenCV DLLs are available to your application if you build the application as Release in Visual Studio.

I've accidentally placed the DLLs with the suffix "d" in the working directory of my application which was build as "Release". This caused the problem.